# Windows phone facebook app navigation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm learning Windows Phone development and I have some trouble to identify how the facebook app is working for the navigation.

[image: Facebook Screenshot]

Could you please tell me what is the component for navigation in red?

Also, what is the green component to support sliding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top navigation with icons can be done by using the `Pivot` control and a `ListBox` that are both linked together with the selected index.
Complete example can be found here http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/08/29/twitterate-your-windows-phone-app/

For creating that side slide panel, I would suggest you use this control https://slideview.codeplex.com/ because there is no standard one in the current WP8 framework. ( in Windows 10 there is a `SplitView` that can do this )